# Emerald installation, texmaker and ubuntu

Tags: fonts, installing, installing-fonts

I have followed the steps that were shown [here](http://www.deanbodenham.com/learn/beamer-installing-emerald.html) in order to install to install emerald in my Ubuntu. I performed the check that is suggested in the link in my terminal and it seems that I have done everything properly. Below you can see a photo

[image]

However, when I tried to execute the minimal example that is provided in the link that I have provided, it does not generate a pdf file.

Below, I give the code that I used in my TeXmakeR

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  
\begin{document}
  
\ECFJD
This is ECFJD.

  
\vspace{1cm}
  
\ECFAugie
This is ECFAugie
  
\end{document}
```

After I compile, I don't get any error messages; it just does not produce a pdf output.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit 1: After the comment below, I am pasting the content of the .log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.10.17)  7 MAY 2021 18:09
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**presentation_1.tex
(./presentation_1.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 9 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./emerald.sty
Package: emerald 2006/01/26 v1.0 LaTeX2e package which gives support for ECF (e
merald city fontwerks) fonts
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (./presentation_1.aux)
\openout1 = `presentation_1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+fjd on input line 7.
 (/home/konstantinos/texmf/tex/latex/emerald/t1fjd.fd
File: t1fjd.fd 2006/01/25 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/fjd.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+fau on input line 13.

(/home/konstantinos/texmf/tex/latex/emerald/t1fau.fd
File: t1fau.fd 2006/01/25 Fontinst v1.926 font definitions for T1/fau.
) [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./presentation_1.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 467 strings out of 494805
 4726 string characters out of 6177999
 49859 words of memory out of 5000000
 3864 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6092 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 81 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,17p,190b,115s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 <
/home/konstantinos/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm1000.
600pk>
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file faumw8r): Font faumw8r at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: show the complete log-file.

Comment: please see my edit. thanks a lot

Comment: you get an error see the last line of your log-file.  Add \pdfmapfile{=emerald.map} to your document and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. This resolved the issue. I thought that since in the error box on the texmaker there was not a single red notification there were no errors. If you want to add some details and post it as an answer, I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you installed to `TEXMFHOME`, that is, under your user directory, `~/texmf/`. This means the map file did not get updated when you updated the system maps.

The best solution is to install to `TEXMFLOCAL` instead. That is, `sudo mkdir $(kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)/emerald` and unpack the archive there.  Run `sudo texhash` and `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map emerald.map`.

You could also `updmap-usr --enable Map emerald.map`, but then you **must** re-run `updmap-usr` whenever you update TeX, or any changes to the font maps in your distribution will not update.  It’s a trap.

Or you can download [the TrueType versions](https://web.archive.org/web/20120719055112/http://www.speakeasy.org/%7Eecf/alphabet.htm) of the Emerald City Fontwerks fonts, from the Internet Archive, to your `~/.fonts/` directory (or `/usr/local/share/fonts/`, or several other places).  These will work in LuaTeX or XeTeX with `fontspec`.